# The probability that all 8 teams loses at least one game and wins at least one game in a tournament?

Tags: probability

Question:

> Eight teams compete in a tournament. Each pair of teams plays exactly
>   one game against each other. There are no ties. If the two possible
>   outcomes of each game are equally likely, what is the probability that
>   every team loses at least one game and wins at least one game?

I found this question on 2017 Fermat Competition of Waterloo University. The original solution seems a bit wordy and redundant. I wonder if there is a way to **solve the probability in more simplified approaches**? [Original Solution (Page 8)](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2017/2017FermatSolution.pdf)

Comment: I mean, much of what they say isn't strictly necessary to say. But the solution isn't really that long. And what is it about the solution which you find "un-algebraic"? Do they not use enough symbols for your taste?

Comment: I can understand the solution that they provided. However, I reckon there should be algebraic solutions that are more explicit and systematic. I have found some of the official Waterloo Contest solution to be redundant before. I agree that more mathematical symbol doesn't make the solution better. But an explicit answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that team${_k}$  loses its seven matches is $2^{-7}={1\over128}$. The probability that one of the eight teams loses its seven matches therefore is $8\cdot{1\over128}={1\over16}$, and similarly, the probability that one of the eight teams wins its seven matches is ${1\over16}$. The probability that at least one of these two events occurs is ${1\over16}+{1\over16}$ *minus* the probability that both occur at the same time. The latter is ${8\over128}\cdot{7\over64}={7\over1024}$: We can choose in $8$ ways the team${_k}$ that loses $7$ times and then in $7$ ways the team that wins against team${_k}$ and $6$ other  teams.

It follows that the probability $p$ for having nothing of these is given by
$$p=1-\left({1\over16}+{1\over16}-{7\over1024}\right)={903\over1024}\ .$$

Comment: That's much more straightforward. Thank you so much!

Comment: It might be a little bit better to write $\frac 8{128} \times \frac 7{64}$ as $\mathrm{2}^{-7} \times 8$ $\times$ $\mathrm{2}^{-6} \times 7$, which would better explains the purpose of this step.

Comment: This is basically the exact same argument, just without all the fluff they fill the page with.